# [ROS2] How to query Quality of Service (QoS) Parameters from Command line

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to query the quality of service (QoS) parameters for ROS2 topics from the command line?  Without the ability to query the QoS from the command line, users have to read the source code that created publishers or subscribers. This isn't a good option in the long run. I've run into mismatched QoS parameters when using NAV2, RVIZ2 and robot_state_publisher because they use custom QoS parameters; thus, messages are not received without any ability to debug the problem. I've read about new users' frustrations with ROS2 on GitHub issues because the QoS parameters are opaque.

I understand exposing the QoS parameters through the rclpy and rclcpp APIs is probably tedious, not fun, and maybe no one is paying for it. Is there a workaround (besides reading source code)?

There was one question about this feature years ago, but it has been ignored:
https://answers.ros.org/question/304946/ros2-retrieving-qos-settings-for-a-topic/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370873/%5Bros2%5D-how-to-query-quality-of-service-(qos)-parameters-from-command-line/) by [Kevin DeMarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/5012/kevin-demarco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2021-02-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Isn't this output by `ros2 topic info --verbose`?

From the usage text:

```
  --verbose, -v  Prints detailed information like the node name, node namespace, topic type, GUID and QoS Profile of the publishers and subscribers to this topic
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin DeMarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/5012/kevin-demarco/) on 2021-02-02**:
Thanks, that's what I was looking for! I am going to see if I can add this to the ROS2 tutorial documentation.

**Comment by [rugved](https://answers.ros.org/users/75152/rugved/) on 2021-07-12**:
Is it not available for ros2 dashing? For the it says --verbose argument not recognized

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-07-13**:
No, I don't believe it is.

The OP also asked about Foxy.